# unix socket send() succeeds, but recv() fails

Tags: c, sockets, unix, send, recv

I am writing a simple client server program using unix domain sockets, but am having issues with the recv() call in my client program.

The program executes as follows:

- Server sets up socket and waits for a connection
- Client connects and sends a string
- Server receives string, and sends string back to client (like an echo)
- Client recv() call fails, returning "resource temporarily unavailable"
- Client exits
- Server waits for another connection

I have also tried using a poll() call in my client to wait for the response from the server.
In this case however, the recv() call simply receives a 0, implying the connection has been closed serverside, which it has not.

I have exhausted google on this error, but no fixes I came accross seem applicable to my code.

I have included my client (with poll() code commented out) and server code below.

I'm probably missing something obvious... but any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Server code:

```
    /*
 *  testServer.c
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "/var/run/ts.serv" 

void handleSockIO(int *sockDesc);

int main ()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_un sock_addr;
    int len, p;
    struct pollfd poll_fd[1];

    printf("[TS] testServer Started.\r\n");

    if ((sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("[TS]wr_sock creation");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("[TS] Created socket descriptor.\r\n");
    }


    sock_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(sock_addr.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    unlink(sock_addr.sun_path);

    len = strlen(sock_addr.sun_path) + sizeof(sock_addr.sun_family);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sock_addr, len) == -1) 
    {
        perror("[TS]sock bind failed\r\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("[TS] Bound socket to sock_addr.\r\n");
    }

    if (listen(sock, 5) == -1) 
    {
        perror("[TS] sock listen fail");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("[TS] Socket now listening.\r\n");
    }

    poll_fd[0].fd = sock;
    poll_fd[0].events = POLLIN;

    printf("[TS] Waiting for a connection...\r\n");

    while (1) 
    {
        p = poll(poll_fd, 1, 1); //Wait for 1 ms for data

        if (p == -1) 
        {
            perror("[TS] Poll");
        } 
        else if (p == 0) 
        {
            //printf("Timeout occurred!\n"); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (poll_fd[0].revents & POLLIN)//Data available to read without blocking
            { 
                printf("[TS] Data available on sock..\r\n");
                handleSockIO(&sock);

                printf("[TS] Waiting for another connection...\r\n");
            }
        }
    }//While(1)

    return 0;
}

void handleSockIO(int *sockDesc)
{
    int ioSock, n;
    socklen_t t;
    struct sockaddr_un remote_addr;
    char str[15];

    memset(str, ' ', sizeof(str));

    t = sizeof(remote_addr);

    if ((ioSock = accept(*sockDesc, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, &t)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("accept failed\r\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("[TS] Receiving...\r\n");

        n = recv(ioSock, str, sizeof(str), 0);

        if (n < 0) 
            printf("[TS] recvfrom failed: %s\r\n", strerror(errno));
        else if(n == 0)
        {
            printf("[TS] Received %d on ioSock...\r\n", n);
        }
        else if(n > 0)
        {
            printf("[TS] Received: %s, which is %d long.\r\n", str, strlen(str));

            printf("[TS] Echoing response...\r\n");

            if (send(ioSock, str, n, 0) == -1) //Echo str back
            {
                printf("[TS] send failed: %s\r\n", strerror(errno));
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("[TS] Send successful\r\n");
            }

            //============Wait to close IO descriptor=================
            int r;
            char temp[1]; //Arbitrary buffer to satisfy recv()
            do 
            {
                printf("[TS] Waiting for client to close connection...\r\n");
                r = recv(ioSock, temp, sizeof(temp), 0);

                if (r == 0)
                {
                    printf("[TS] Client closed connection, closing ioSock...\r\n");
                    close(ioSock);
                }
            } while (r != 0);

            //========================================================
        }//if(n>0) else...
    }       
}
```

Client code:

```
 /*
 *  testClient.c
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define CHAR_BUF_SIZE 15
#define SEND_STRING "Hello!"
#define SOCK_PATH "/var/run/ts.serv" 

int main ()
{
    char str[CHAR_BUF_SIZE] = {0};
    int c, len, n, p;
    int s; // s will hold a socket descriptor returned by socket()
    struct sockaddr_un serv_addr;
    struct pollfd poll_fd[1];

    printf("[TC] testClient Started.\r\n");

    //===============SOCKET SETUP===============================

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        printf("[TC] Socket failed: %s\r\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(serv_addr.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);

    len = strlen(serv_addr.sun_path) + sizeof(serv_addr.sun_family);

    //==========================================================

    //  printf("[TC]Trying to connect to TS socket...\r\n");

    //===============RESPONSE POLL SETUP========================

    poll_fd[0].fd = s;
    poll_fd[0].events = POLLIN;

    //==========================================================

    printf("[TC] Connecting to SOCK_PATH...\r\n");

    c = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, len);

    if (c == -1)
    {
        printf("[TC] Connection failed: %s\r\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("[TC] Connected. Sending string....\r\n");

        if (send(s, SEND_STRING, strlen(SEND_STRING), 0) == -1) 
        {
            printf("[TC] send() failed: %s\r\n", strerror(errno));
        }
        else 
        { 
            printf("[TC] Send on SOCK_PATH successful.\r\n");
            //Sending complete------------------------------------------------
            //Wait for response...

            printf("[TC] Waiting for server response...\r\n");

//          p = poll(poll_fd, 1, -1); //Wait for a response
//          
//          if (p == -1) 
//          {
//              perror("[TC] Poll");
//          } 
//          else 
//          {
//              if(poll_fd[0].revents & POLLIN)
//              {
                    n = recv(s, str, sizeof(str), 0);

                    if (n < 0) 
                    {
                        printf("[TC] Receive on SOCK_PATH failed: %s\r\n", 
                               strerror(errno));
                    }
                    else if(n == 0)
                    {
                        printf("[TC] %d Received on SOCK_PATH.\r\n", n);
                    }
                    else if(n > 0)
                    {
                        printf("[TC] Received %d from SOCK_PATH: %s\r\n", 
                               n, str);
                    }
//              }
//          }
        }//if(send())
    }//if(connect())

    printf("[TC] Transction complete, closing connection and exiting.\r\n");

    close(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `unsigned int t` shall be `socklen_t t`.

Comment: Change all the `strlen(x)` parameters in the `recv()` calls to `sizeof x`, replacing `x` as necessary in each case. It doesn't make sense to measure the length of a string you haven't received yet, or to prefill the receive buffer just so you can do so. There's no real need to block in `recv()` before closing the socket.

Comment: there are a lot errors, like `len = strlen(serv_addr.sun_path) + sizeof(serv_addr.sun_family);` instead of `len = sizeof(serv_addr)`
`

Comment: Thankyou EJP,  i have edited the code above to include sizeof() in place of strlen().
The looped recv() call in the server code was merely me testing to ensure that the client calls close() first... in order to test the recv() returning 0 case.

Comment: Thankyou @MaxFomichev! Fixing the len value to the sizeof a sockaddr_un structure fixed the issue.
Could you add your comment as an answer please so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: Oh look!  The magic strlen() again :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len = sizeof(serv_addr)` instead of `len = strlen(serv_addr.sun_path) + sizeof(serv_addr.sun_family)` should solve you problem. Also do not ignore compiler warnings, say `n = recv(s, str, strlen(str), 0)` with n declared as int and ssize_t returned by recv. It will help you to avoid a future errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And fyi this did not throw up any compiler warnings on my arm device, it was quite happy to assign recv's return value to an int with no cast.

Comment: You are welcome, any way, ssize_t/size_t/etc can differ from one OS/platform to another.